Git/GitHub - There's nothing to compare
Let's say you have two branches: main and develop. A conflict exists between them, which needs to be resolved locally before pushing any changes to the remote repository. This conflict was caused by a hotfix that was merged into both main and develop using separate commits.
You follow these steps to resolve the conflict:

Update your local branches.
Merge the changes from main into develop and resolve the conflicts.
After resolving them, create a new branch from develop called resolve-conflicts.
Push the changes from the resolve-conflicts branch to the remote repository.
Finally, attempt to create a pull request to merge changes from the resolve-conflicts branch back into develop.

However, you might encounter a message on GitHub saying, "There is nothing to compare," which would prevent you from creating the pull request. This situation likely arises because the changes in resolve-conflicts are already present in develop. But still, you must update origin/develop with the changes from resolve-conflicts to resolve the conflict between origin/main and origin/develop.
So, I have two questions:

If there are no differences between origin/resolve-conflicts and origin/develop, why does GitHub prevent you from merging origin/develop into origin/main?
Is there a way to update origin/develop while eliminating the conflict between origin/main and origin/develop, bearing in mind that pushing directly to origin/develop is not permitted?


What happens if you merge resolve-conflicts into develop locally?

"But still, you must update origin/develop with the changes from resolve-conflicts to resolve the conflict between origin/main and origin/develop." Why must you? If resolve-conflicts has no differences from origin/develop, what's the point of merging it at all? Just throw it away. origin/develop already looks just the way you want it to.

This situation, as stated, should not be possible. You are allowed to create and complete pull requests even if the two branches have no git diff between them, as long as they still have commit IDs to merge. In your contrived example, even if the branches have the same state, there would still be a new merge commit which could be merged, even if it didn't change the resulting state of develop.
